# UIScrollView with two UIView's Layers (one should not be zoomed)

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uiview, uiscrollview

I want to make a thing like Maps application.
I've a UIScrollView with two views:

1. [BACKGROUND] UIView with an image
   (suppose a pdf page)
2. [OBJECTS LAYER] UIView on top (always inside the UIScrollView)
   where I want to draw/place some objects (ie UIImageViews with pins like in Google Maps)

Is possible to disable zoom for my second view. [OBJECTS LAYER] should not be zoomed and objects should remain at the same position (obviously the position is re-caculcated using the zoomScale of UIScrollView) and with the same size (no zoom should be applied).
How can I accomplish it?

Answer (score 0):

The solution is:

1. Place [OBJECTS LAYER] as direct
   child of UIScrollView
2. Set [OBJECTS LAYER] to be auto-resizable in width/height
3. Recalculate position of objects inside (ie.pins) using the scale
   (newX=oldX*scale,newY=oldY*scale).

Hope it helps :)